# How to generate this model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner with Ruby on Rails but am trying to create my own application.

I've added users and a few models but am stuck on something.... I am trying to create a model called 'JOBS' with the following items:

- Job Title
- Job Category
- Job Tags
- Fixed Price or Hourly
- Budget
- Timeframe
- Description
- Files
- Submit Button

Im not sure how to get the file upload form in there...

If someone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you try the [**CarrierWave gem**](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave).

The docs are excellent, and show you how to create an upload form. CarrierWave is what many Rails professionals choose to use because it offers many conveniences, ways to upload multiple files at once, multiple backend storage systems such as Amazon S3, etc.

For example, you could write a job that has a title and image like this:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Alternatively, if you're interested in learning how to do it in Rails without any gem, then read the [**Rails guides on form helpers for uploading files**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files)

For example, you could write a form that has a job title and image like this:

```
<%= form_for @job do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: For file uploading in forms I think you usually need to add ```:multipart => true``` to the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading to Amazon S3 i found that using the Paperclip gem was pretty straight forward.

Here is a walkthrough from Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3